# Why is 'align-content:start' is applied on one-line items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I just learned that 'align-content' property works only if there are more than one line. Because this property is all about between lines of items.
so if there is just one line, this property must not have impact.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

html {
  background: #b3b3b3;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  background: #b3b3b3;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 1300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content:flex-start
}

.item-1 {
  background: #ff7300;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-2 {
  background: #ff9640;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.item-3 {
  background: #ff9640;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 250px;
}

.item-4 {
  background: #f5c096;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.item-5 {
  background: #d3c0b1;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}

.item-6 {
  background: #d3c0b1;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title>Flexbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="item-1">div</div>
            <div class="item-2">w=250px</div>
            <div class="item-3">h=250px</div>
            <div class="item-4">w/h=300px</div>
            <div class="item-5">w=350px</div>
            <div class="item-6">w=350px</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but in this case, I applied

```
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content:flex-start
```

According to what I learned, the align-content should not work because there is just one line. So the items should be on the center of the 'flex-container'.

but it's placed on the top like below which it should not be
[image]

could you explain about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`align-content` in `flexbox` will take effect if you use `flex-wrap: wrap`. It's a `flex-flow` property in your case where you've set it to `wrap`. That's why it takes effect even if there is a single line.

Comment: I'm taking a css lecture, the teacher set `flex-wrap : wrap` which is same code above. and the `align-conetent` didn't take effect.. and when he decrease the with and turned into 2 line, the align-content took effect. the lines poped up to the top.

Comment: I think this answer is correct.  But I am curious to know when you said ```align-content``` didn't take effect in your teacher's lecture. Can you show that here or reproduce an example like that?

Comment: I can't shared the video source due to copyright. It's Udemy lecture : https://www.udemy.com/course/css-the-complete-guide-incl-flexbox-grid-sass/ , lecture number 200, ' and what about "align-content"? , 0:58

Comment: @LICON99 I've watched the lecture you mentioned, I can only guess that there was an implementation difference back then when the course content is recorded in the instructor's browser.

Comment: Yes I think so too. I realized it's been over than 5 years since this lecture released. Thank you so much for you kind :)

Answer (score 0):

> I just learned that 'align-content' property works only if there are more than one line. Because this property is all about between lines of items. so if there is just one line, this property must not have impact.

This is actually wrong. If you check [the Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property) you can read:

> ... Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.

Now if you click on "single-line" you can read:

> A single-line flex container (i.e. one with flex-wrap: nowrap)
>
> A multi-line flex container (i.e. one with flex-wrap: wrap or flex-wrap: wrap-reverse)

So it's the `flex-wrap` property that dictates the behavior, not the number of lines. If you use `wrap` then you have a "multi-line flex container" even if the number of lines is 1.

That's what is happening in your case since you are using `flex-flow: wrap row`

Comment: Thank you. I see it apparently in the document. but the lecture used `flex-wrap:wrap` though. Is there any chance the property mechanism has changed??

Comment: @LICON99 *but the lecture used flex-wrap:wrap though* --> and this is why the align-content is working. Exactly what I am explaining and what you are getting and the mechanism was always like that since years now

Comment: What I meant is that the lecturer applied the `wrap` property to the container, but the `align-content` was not applied until he reduced the container's width and it became two lines.

Comment: This lecuture has been 4 years. So I reckon there was CSS updating...

Comment: @LICON99 this behavior has more than 4 years as well. I am not sure why are you trying to consider that "lecture" that only you are able to see? You asked a clear question, you gave the code, we gave you answers that validated what you see. What do you want more?